# Local LWC server - there are no components present

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin

I wanted to try out the local development Salesforce feature in VSCode. I am able to run the server, I am able to approach localhost:3333/ but I am unable to see any LWCs.

In our org we are not using the standard Salesforce folder structure. So the code is not located in force-app folder. Instead, in root of the project, we have src folder with the more-or-less same content as the force-app folder has.

So I have adjusted the sfdx-project.json file to this:

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "src",
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://test.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "48.0"
}
```

But still, the preview displays no components. Any idea what could be wrong here?
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So apparently it is only possible to run the preview for SFDX projects. If the structure is not in DX, the preview won't run.